# ¿Cuando y como usar las interfaces Set y Map?

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo a usar Set y Map.
Lo primero quería saber si Set y Map son Colecciones y ademas interfaces.
y que me confirmeis que todo lo que digo es correcto.
Set y SortedSet  son hijas de colecction.
Map y SortedMap  son hijas de colecction.
Set  es implementada por HashSet y LinkedHashSet.
Map es implementada  por HashMap y LinkedHashMap.
SortedSet implementa  treeSet.
sortedMap implementa  treeMap.
Nose si hay algún sitio que enfoque en este tema.
El siguiente paso seria saber como cuando y donde usarlos.

Answer (score 3):

Las interfaces `Set` y `Map` no están relacionadas (a excepción de los métodos `keySet()` y `entrySet()` de la interfaz `Map` que devuelve `Sets` respaldados por `Map`).

Sin embargo, varias implementaciones `Set` utilizan una implementación `Map` de respaldo para almacenar sus datos (los elementos de las claves `Set` de conversión en el subyacente `Map`, y los valores del subyacente `Map` son solo objetos ficticios). Esto es cierto para `HashSet` y `TreeSet`.

Esto se menciona en el [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

> clase pública **HashSet**
>   extends AbstractSet 
>   implementa Set, Cloneable, Serializable
>
> Esta clase implementa la interfaz Set, **respaldada por una tabla hash (en realidad una instancia de HashMap**).

Y [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html):

> la clase pública TreeSet extiende AbstractSet  implementa
>   NavigableSet, Cloneable, Serializable
>
> Una implementación de **NavigableSet basada en un TreeMap**.

---

Ejemplo:

```
  public boolean More ...add(E e) {
     return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

Aquí, `PRESENT` es un objeto ficticio de valor estático que debe mantenerse en el mapa de referencia.

```
private static final Object PRESENT = new Object();
```

El objeto Backing Map se crea cuando invocamos varios construtors de `HashSet`:

```
public More ...HashSet() {
    map = new HashMap<E,Object>();
   }

public More... HashSet (Colección c) {
    map = new HashMap (Math.max ((int) (c.size () /. 75f) + 1, 16));
    addAll (c); 
  }

 public More... HashSet (int initialCapacity, float loadFactor) {
     map = new HashMap (initialCapacity, loadFactor);
   }
```

[image]

Consulte javadocs para otras implementaciones de conjuntos respaldadas por Map.

Comment: No queria decir que se complementaban , si no que tenian un uso paralelo.

Comment: @DavidPalanco mmmm no me queda claro que quiere decir con eso, mire esto https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html

Comment: Creo que queda claro con "Las interfaces Set y Map no están relacionadas", como concepto son dos tipos de colecciones para usos muy distintos, Map para guardar valores en base a una llave, set para garantizar solo un elemento en el arreglo, así que realmente ni siquiera son intercambiables, y los casos en que aplica uno u otro creo que son claros en base a sus funcionalidades

Comment: @rekiem87 buen comentario!